# How to switch between layouts in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm working on android app and I want to slide between pages with different content. For this I use `ViewPager`. It's new to me, so I used [this project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) as an example. My problem's that I don't know how to put content on different pages. To put it simply - how can I make on 1st page some text, on another - image, and on the 3rd one - a button? 
Is it achieved by different layouts or somehow else?

Here are codes I use:

SampleTabsStyled.java

```
public class SampleTabsStyled extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
}

class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }


  }
}
```

simple_tabs.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**[UPDATE]**

I've written simple TestFragment.java, that should display different layout.
The problem's that in line `return TestFragment.newInstance();`, I get this error

```
The method newInstance() is undefined for the type TestFragment
```

TestFragment.java

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sideview, null);       
    } 
}
```

And here's MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres" };

    TestFragment TestFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TestFragment = new TestFragment();


        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return TestFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:

            /*case 1:
                return ImageFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return ButtonFragment.newInstance(); */
        }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should to make a class that extends from fragment.
then you override the oncreateview method that returns a view.
in there you can inflate a custom for example in first you inflate layout that have text in second you inflate the layout that have image and ....

to know which layout should inflate you can pass the position to new instance method.

and in the fragment class you can have a field that shows the position of the page.you instantiate it in new instance and use it in oncreateview

in every getItem of the adapter you make a new instance of the fragmentclass and you can customize it with the position of the fragment.

hope it was useful

EDITED :

this is your fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public int position;

public static MyFragment newInstance(int position){
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    myFragment.setPosition(position);
    return new MyFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fView;
    if(position == 0){
        fView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout);
    }else if(position == 1){
        fView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout);
    }else{
        fView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout);
        Button b = fView.findViewById(R.id.button)
    }
    return fView;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}
}
```

and now call newinstance like this MyFragment.newInstance(positoin);

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail or send a link for a tutorial? Because frankly, I didn't understand how to do half of what you said.

Answer (score 1):

The key for resolving your problem is `getItem(int position)` method, you use the same fragment for every page (`TestFragment`):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
}
```

Instead of this approach you can use separated fragments for every page (for example fragment with text, fragment with image, etc.)

And your `getItem(int position)` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return TextFragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return ImageFragment.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return ButtonFragment.newInstance(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @OleksandrFirsov actually you choose not my approach :) But still, are you sure your fragment class has `newInstance()` method with `public static` access. You can read about `newInstance()` pattern [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html)

Answer (score 0):

`getItem` should return the `Fragment` (which is a page) at the specified position. I'm not sure what your code was intended to do?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
}
```

You should instead, create a fragment for each page, and assign it to a position, for example:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            return new MyFragment();
        case 1:
            return new MyFragment1();
        case 2:
            return new MyFragment2();
        //...
    }
}
```